# How to scroll to row in table which is using overflow for scrollbars?

Tags: html

I have a table which needs to be scrollable within a single page.  I've used a jQuery scrollable table plugin to accomplish this but now I need to figure out how to scroll to a specific row.

I've tried a few different methods including:

```
$.scrollTo($('#rowIWantToScrollTo'));
```

and

```
var rowpos = $('#rowIWantToScrollTo').position();

$('#myTable').scrollTop(rowpos.top);
```

and

```
$('#rowIWantToScrollTo').scrollIntoView();
```

And nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What jQuery scrollable table plugin did you use? Perhaps, it has the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: The one called jquery scrollable table plugin and it doesn't contain the functionality.  Is there one you know of that does?

Comment: No I don't. Just trying to see if I can be of any help. [Is it this one that you are using?](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/).

Comment: Yup.. that's the one I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8AYvW/2/)**

Here's how to do it. (You were close).

1) Fetch top offset of element using offset() and .top

2) Scroll to element using ScrollTo

I broke it up a bit for illustration purposes.

Javascript:

```
$("a").click(function(e){

  var _offset = $(".row9").offset();
  var _topoffset = _offset.top;

  $(".scrollbox").scrollTop(_topoffset);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work nor does the example you linked to work in Chrome or IE8.

Comment: It actually does work. It appears jsfiddle reset it to use "MooTools" and not "jQuery". I've updated it to jQuery and you can check the updated demo to confirm: http://jsfiddle.net/8AYvW/2/

Comment: Weird.  I had changed it back to jQuery and it still didn't work but your updated demo works great.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right @ShaneCourtrille. From what I can see, there is no functionality inbuilt in the plugin to scroll to a particular row.

Below is a very simple solution using hyperlinks. Not sure if this is what you want, but it does the job...

Create an internal anchor like this...

```
<tr>
    <td><a name="toHere"></a>FL</td>
    <td>$1,364.27</td>
    <td>$712.05</td>
    <td>$211.11</td>
    <td>$416.87</td>
    <td>$1,364.27</td>
    <td>$712.05</td>
    <td>$211.11</td>
    <td>$416.87</td>
</tr>
```

and link it outside the table - `<a href="#toHere">Scroll to my specified row</a>`

I just did a brief search and there are other plugins out there. One is [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/index).

There are few more plugins listed in the following link that might be of help to you...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations